# Applying a common font scheme to multiple objects in wxPython

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython

Many times I will use the same font scheme for static text in a wxPython application. Currently I am making a `SetFont()` call for each static text object but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work. However, the wxPython demo and wxPython In Action book don't discuss this.

Is there a way to easily apply the same `SetFont()` method to all these text objects without making separate calls each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by calling SetFont on the parent window (Frame, Dialog, etc) before adding any widgets.  The child widgets will inherit the font.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try subclassing the text object and in your class `__init__` method just call SetFont()?

Or, do something like:

```
def f(C):
  x = C()
  x.SetFont(font) # where font is defined somewhere else
  return x
```

and then just decorate every text object you create with with it:

```
text = f(wx.StaticText)
```

(of course, if `StaticText` constructor requires some parameters, it will require changing the first lines in `f` function definition).

Answer (score 0):

If all widgets have already been created, you can apply `SetFont` recursively, for example with the following function:

```
def changeFontInChildren(win, font):
    '''
    Set font in given window and all its descendants.
    @type win: L{wx.Window}
    @type font: L{wx.Font}
    '''
    try:
        win.SetFont(font)
    except:
        pass # don't require all objects to support SetFont
    for child in win.GetChildren():
        changeFontInChildren(child, font)
```

An example usage that causes all text in `frame` to become default font with italic style:

```
newFont = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
newFont.SetStyle(wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC)
changeFontInChildren(frame, newFont)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given above by @DzinX worked for me when changing the font dynamically in a Panel that already had children and was already being shown.

I ended up modifying it as follows because the original gave me trouble in corner cases (i.e. when using an `AuiManager` with Floating frames).

```py
def change_font_in_children(win, font):
    '''
    Set font in given window and all its descendants.
    @type win: L{wx.Window}
    @type font: L{wx.Font}
    '''
    for child in win.GetChildren():
        change_font_in_children(child, font)
    try:
        win.SetFont(font)
        win.Update()
    except:
        pass # don't require all objects to support SetFont
```